# interrupted system call with processing queue

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

We suddenly started see "Interrupted system call" on Queue operations like this:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
[ . . . ]
   result = self.pager.results.get(True, self.WAIT_SECONDS)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/processing-0.52-py2.5-linux-x86_64.egg/processing/queue.py", line 128, in get
   if not self._poll(block and (deadline-time.time()) or 0.0):
IOError: [Errno 4] Interrupted system call
```

This is a Fedora 10 / Python 2.5 machine that recently had a security update.  Prior to that our software had run for about a year without incident, now it is crashing daily.

Is it correct/necessary to catch this exception and retry the Queue operation?

We don't have any signal handlers that we set, but this is a Tkinter app maybe it sets some.  Is it safe to clear the SIGINT handler, would that solve the problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Obvious point, but a sudden regression after an update sounds like it could be a bug in a package you're relying on. Have you investigated what the update changed?

Comment: Good idea, I checked yum.log and there were 580 updated packages. None of the Python ones seemed like a problem. We have Fedora 12 and 13 machines which seem to be working.  If the problem is specific to "Fedora 10 + updates" I'm willing to consider updating to the newest Fedora.

Comment: We've now seen this on a Fedora 14 machine, Python 2.7.

Comment: I am facing the same problem , @Philip thanks for the googlegroup link. It was very helpful in understanding the underlying problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.python/browse_thread/thread/ae3cf5d475c4f1ba) on comp.lang.python and [this reply](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/595310/) from Dan Stromberg I wrote a RetryQueue which is a drop-in replacement for Queue and which does the job for us:

```
from multiprocessing.queues import Queue
import errno

def retry_on_eintr(function, *args, **kw):
    while True:
        try:
            return function(*args, **kw)
        except IOError, e:            
            if e.errno == errno.EINTR:
                continue
            else:
                raise    

class RetryQueue(Queue):
    """Queue which will retry if interrupted with EINTR."""
    def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        return retry_on_eintr(Queue.get, self, block, timeout)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally this got fixed in python itself, so the other solution is to update to a newer python:
http://bugs.python.org/issue17097